# GraphAPI & FQL query return nothing on some of my friends?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, privacy

I'm developing a mobile app which uses Facebook Graph API and FQL for data mining.

I look through my friends' posts, photos, videos and do some calculations, but recently, I noticed that querying some of my friends return an empty response... How is that possible? I can see their wall posts when I log in to Facebook in my browser, and I can access their photos, videos, etc. But GraphAPI and FQL return nothing.

I have included all the permissions for this, but still nothing... It's a case with just couple of them, but it is really annoying me :/

Is this some privacy thing I don't understand, or what?
Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's API results are spotty at best.  When you encounter friends with bad results, just ignore them from your calculations.